# How to make a box expand a distance from the sides

Tags: javascript, css, css-float

I'd like to know how you make it so that a box(textarea) would expand to fill space, but from a certain pixel distance (not percentage) just enough to fit a menu on each side. Is this possible?

I've tried as many CSS properties as I could find, but none of them seem to work correctly. (note, I'm fine with using javascript if required)

My specific page: http://pastebin.com/5adPwXEE

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @xixonia Does that help?

Comment: I was hoping for an example of the result. Perhaps you've seen what you want somewhere else, and could provide us a reference?

Comment: I've never seen it done on a web page except using frameset, I'd just copy it if I had.

Comment: If you're fine with using Javascript get the viewport width - menu width - whatever padding you want and set that to the width.

Comment: Not really sure how to do that though

Comment: This is how original code renders: http://jsfiddle.net/RMGzS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think you need javascript for this, you just need to isolate your chat *division* into a `div` (which is exactly what they're for ;))

This div will be 100% wide by default - then you margin it on both sides to clear your 2 x absolutely positioned lists.. then the `textarea`s that sit inside it can be 100% of the "chat div".. you then remove the padding off the body element as you don't need it

I added `div class="chat"` and removed all unnecessary CSS

#### Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/rmRUT/)

Comment: Thank you, especially for fixing my code (instead of just telling me how), much appreciated.